# Cmake/SWIG combination doesn't play well within virtual environment

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x, cmake, swig

I am working on a project that combines Python 3 with C++, so I decided to work with CMake + SWIG. I have the problem that when I type 'make' with the virtual environment active, I get missing symbols because it seems that the versions of Python found are not compatible:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /Users/aaragon/.virtualenvs/pydev/bin/python (found version "3.4.2") 
-- Found SWIG: /usr/local/bin/swig (found version "3.0.5") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython3.4.dylib (found version "2.7.6")
```

so I get the following errors:

```
Linking CXX shared module _core.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyClass_Type", referenced from:
      SwigPyClientData_New(_object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyInstance_NewRaw", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance(SwigPyClientData*, _object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyInstance_Type", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_GetSwigThis(_object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyInt_AsLong", referenced from:
      SWIG_AsVal_long(_object*, long*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SWIG_AsVal_unsigned_SS_long(_object*, unsigned long*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SWIG_AsVal_double(_object*, double*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyInt_FromLong", referenced from:
      SWIG_From_int(int) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyInt_FromSize_t", referenced from:
      SWIG_From_unsigned_SS_int(unsigned int) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_AsString", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_str_AsChar(_object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_AsStringAndSize", referenced from:
      SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize(_object*, char**, unsigned long*, int*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_ConcatAndDel", referenced from:
      SwigPyObject_repr(SwigPyObject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      swig_varlink_str(swig_varlinkobject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_Format", referenced from:
      SwigPyObject_format(char const*, SwigPyObject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_FromFormat", referenced from:
      SwigPyObject_repr(SwigPyObject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SwigPyPacked_repr(SwigPyPacked*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SwigPyPacked_str(SwigPyPacked*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_FromString", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_str_FromChar(char const*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      swig_varlink_repr(swig_varlinkobject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      swig_varlink_str(swig_varlinkobject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_FromStringAndSize", referenced from:
      SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize(char const*, unsigned long) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_Py_InitModule4_64", referenced from:
      _init_core in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SWIG_Python_SetModule(swig_module_info*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "__PyInstance_Lookup", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_GetSwigThis(_object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [_core.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [core] Error 2
```

When I'm outside the environment everything works fine:

```
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.6") 
-- Found SWIG: /usr/local/bin/swig (found version "3.0.5") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.dylib (found version "2.7.6")
```

except for the fact that I don't want to work with Python 2.7.6, but with Python 3. Is there a way to fix this error? This is the code I'm currently using within the CMakeLists.txt:

```
# find Python
find_package(PythonInterp)

# find SWIG
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

message(STATUS "PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH: ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}")
message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES:    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/core)
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/core/fem)

#set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/../lib/hybrida)


SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(swig/core.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_source_files_properties(swig/core.i SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall;-c++;-shadow")
swig_add_module(core python swig/core.i core/foo.cpp)
swig_link_libraries(core hybrida_core ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your virtual environment with needed Python version:

```
virtualenv --python /path/to/python <venv_dir>
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I created the virtualenv using the lazy wrapper as follows: `$ mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/local/bin/python3 pydev3` but it still fails.